# Find polynomial whose root is sum of roots of $X^5 - 2$ and $X^4 - 3$

Tags: polynomials, galois-theory, roots

I have a task where I need to find a polynomial $R \in \mathbb{Q}[X]$ that has roots $\alpha + \beta$ where $\alpha$ are arbitrary roots of $X^5 - 2$ and $\beta$ of $X^4 - 3\enspace.$

The general technique to use is obvious to me, the polynomial is given by
$$
  R = \prod_{i, j} (x - (\alpha_i + \beta_j))
$$
with the corresponding roots
$$
\begin{align*}
  \alpha_1 &= \sqrt[5]{2}\\
  \alpha_2 &= -\sqrt[5]{-2}\\
  \alpha_3 &= (-1)^{\frac{2}{5}}\sqrt[5]{2}\\
  \alpha_4 &= -(-1)^{\frac{3}{5}}\sqrt[5]{2}\\
  \alpha_5 &= (-1)^{\frac{4}{5}}\sqrt[5]{2}\\
  \beta_1 &= \sqrt[4]{3}\\
  \beta_2 &= -\sqrt[4]{3}\\
  \beta_3 &= i\sqrt[4]{3}\\
  \beta_4 &= -i\sqrt[4]{3}\enspace.
\end{align*}
$$
(compare to questions like [Find polynomial whose root is sum of roots of other polynomials](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/890400/find-polynomial-whose-root-is-sum-of-roots-of-other-polynomials/893826#893826))

---

Now I know that one can argue that $R$ is indeed in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$, but we didn't yet step into Galois-theory so I probably can't use that, nor do I know the details of how to prove this.

The problem with manually computing $R$ is that the resulting equation is huge, really huge. After some hours of *Mathematica magic* I could resolve the above to
$$
\begin{align*}
  S &= X^{20} - 15X^{16} -8X^{15} + 90X^{12} -1560X^{11} + 24X^{10} - 270X^8 - 11160X^7\\
  &\qquad- 4080X^6 - 32X^5 + 405X^4 - 7560X^3 + 3960X^2 - 480X - 227\enspace.
\end{align*}
$$

The problem is that, if I go from this direction, I would need to check all $5 \cdot 4 = 20$ roots. But that is again a huge task.

---

At this point I'm stuck, both directions aren't eligible for a manual approach. I probably need some kind of **fancy argument** with which I can follow that $R = S$ or that $S$ has those roots (despite the fact that $S$ *fall out of the sky*).

Alternatively, arguments that $R$ is in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$ due to construction. But in this case I would need some **guidance** because, as said, I'm not sufficiently acquainted with Galois-theory.

Comment: It's quite easy to write down a $20$-by-$20$ matrix whose characteristic polynomial is your polynomial. Do you like computing characteristic polynomials of large matrices?

Comment: `After some hours of Mathematica magic ...` Or in WA [`resultant[ x^5-2, (z-x)^4 - 3, x ]`](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=resultant%5B+x%5E5-2,+(z-x)%5E4+-+3,+x+%5D), or [`minimalpolynomial[ surd(2,5)+surd(3,4), z ]`](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=minimalpolynomial%5B+surd(2,5)%2Bsurd(3,4),+z+%5D).

Comment: I thijk that you need to know just about symmetric polynomials (which would be MUCH less than Galois Theory).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this this is the argument you want. To be precise, what I want to explain is that for monic irreducible polynomials $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, and their roots $\alpha_i$, $\beta_j$ are the conjugates of the roots of them, respectively, the polynomial 
$$ p(x) = \prod_i \prod_j \left( x-\alpha_i -\beta_j \right) $$
is in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ without referring the Galois theory.

Viewed as a polynomial over $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \ldots , \alpha_n]$, the coefficients of $p(x)$ are symmetric polynomials of $\beta_j$s, say $\sigma_k$ be the degree $k$ elementary symmetric polynomial of $\beta_j$s. Therefore coefficients of $p(x)$ are of the form $B \left( \sigma_1 , \sigma_2 , \ldots , \sigma_m , \alpha_1 , \alpha_2 , \ldots , \alpha_n \right) $. Hence $B$ is a polynomial of $\alpha_i$s with integral coefficients. However, $B$ is also symmetric of $\alpha_i$. Therefore, is an integer. This proves that $p(x)$ is in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$.